# Why would changing a structure size, change the size of an executable?

Tags: c, linux, size, executable

Very strange issue I'm working to debug, currently at a loss so I wanted to see if anyone had any thoughts/ideas.

There's a define in one of the char drivers in my code base (this is one of many drivers within a uCLinux distribution):

```
#define MAX_BUFSIZE 500
```

When I build like this I see the output package size:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mike users 1720620 Jan 16 11:00 gcl-kernel.pkg
```

When I change the define to 1000 and rebuild:

```
#define MAX_BUFSIZE 1000

-rw-rw-r-- 1 mike users 2359596 Jan 16 11:17 gcl-kernel.pkg
```

The overall kernel image greatly increases. That one `#define` was the ***only*** change. AFAIK, this should have changed the RAM size of the executable when running, it should not have done anything to the executable's size.

So my question:

*can anyone think of any reason that a structure being modified would change the final image size?*

---

Other analysis/information if you care:

I tracked usage of this to one structure defined in a header file:

```
typedef struct {
    int head;
    int tail;
    int status;
    int active;
    void * dev[MAX_BUFSIZE];
    char free[MAX_BUFSIZE];
    canmsg_t data[MAX_BUFSIZE];
    int count;
} msg_fifo_t;
```

Anytime I change the size of any of those arrays, the executable size changes. Anytime a new object of this type shows up or is removed in the code the executable size changes, ex:

```
extern msg_fifo_t Tx_Bufx[];
extern msg_fifo_t Rx_Buf[];
```

has a different output executable size then:

```
extern msg_fifo_t Tx_Bufx[];
//extern msg_fifo_t Rx_Buf[];
```

I've tried but I can't seem to create a smaller version of this issue on my x86 system to debug the problem, it must have something to do with the environment. (coldfire tool chain building for a uCLinux 2.4 kernel).

Comment: Does your environment have anything like `.bss` ?

Comment: Your linker can probably produce a map file.  You could use that to see exactly what's going on.

Comment: Maybe a compiler optimization? If it's `gcc`, try compiling with the `-Os`flag.

Comment: In order for the `extern msg_fifo_t Tx_Bufx` to resolve at linkage time there needs to be a declaration of `msg_fifo_t Tx_Bufx` *without* an extern, i.e. in a global context. This is the part that uses the additional memory: compiler prepares a memory segment for your statics and globals, so it grows and shrinks together with the value of `MAX_BUFSIZE`.

Comment: @cnicutar - Good question... not sure at the moment but I'll look into it (`/usr/bin/size` comes back as "file format not recognized" on the output so I need to figure out how to check that)

Comment: @CarlNorum - That's a good point. I'd be surprised if one wasn't being generated already, I'll have to do some searching... there's a huge number of files and directories used in and generated from this build.

Answer (score 3):

If an "instance" of the structure has been declared as `static`, it will be allocated either in the [.BSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) segment or the [.DATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) segment of the binary, depending on whether it was 0 initialized or not. If this is the case, since you're doubling the size of the array, this will increase the final binary size.

Comment: It's a good thought, I don't see any static instances of `msg_fifo_t` anywhere in the code, but it's a big code base... I'll keep looking

Comment: @Mike: notice that here static means not only the `static` keyword, but in general "static storage duration" - i.e. also globals.