# What sections make up the size of an executable?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compilation, size

I'm running a little test while trying to understand a [larger problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366582/why-would-changing-a-structure-size-change-the-size-of-an-executable). Here's my test env:

**head.h**:

```
#define MAX_BUFSIZE 500

typedef struct {
    int head;
    int tail;
    int status;
    int active;
    void * dev[MAX_BUFSIZE];
    char free[MAX_BUFSIZE];
    int count;
} msg_fifo_t;

extern msg_fifo_t TxBufx[];
extern msg_fifo_t Rx_Buf[];
```

**test.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "head.h"

//msg_fifo_t TxBufx[10];  // This is the important line

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    // This part isn't really important...
    printf("Hello Test\n");

    return 0;
 }
```

So I used these files and ran three tests to see what sizes I got -

test #1 (code as is above):

```
> gcc -Os test.c
> ls -al a.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mike mike 7158 Jan 17 11:13 a.out
> size a.out
text   data     bss     dec    hex   filename
1170    256       8    1434    59a   a.out
```

test #2 (uncomment the "important" line):

```
> gcc -Os test.c
> ls -al a.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mike mike 7181 Jan 17 11:14 a.out
> size a.out
text   data     bss     dec    hex   filename
1170    256   25208   26634   680a   a.out
```

test #3 (uncomment the "important" line and change `TxBufx` size to 100)

```
> gcc -Os test.c
> ls -al a.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mike mike 7181 Jan 17 11:14 a.out
> size a.out
text   data     bss     dec    hex   filename
1170    256  252008  253434  3ddfa   a.out
```

So now my questions:

- It would appear that bss size has almost no bearing on the "size" of an executable (as reported from the `ls -al` command) - Can anyone explain to me why that is?
- Is that trait specific to the compiler/linker/or platform?
- Is there a better tool than `size` to understand what is happening here? (meaning what is really making up the 7181 bytes that is my executable?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The amount of data in the `bss` segment has no effect on the size on disk of your executable because of what the `bss` segment is -- this is the section of your program used for variables *initialized to zero*.  Since the content of this section is known in advance (all zeroes), the only thing actually stored in the executable file is the *size* of this region.

So the things that *do* change as your code changes are the size of the `data` segment -- representing variables statically initialized to non-zero values, and the size of the `code` segment, representing the compiled executable instructions corresponding to your program.

As for tools to use, the objdump(1) utility on most Unix systems (it's part of the GNU toolchain) or the otool(1) utility on MacOS X can both be used to get more detailed information about what sections make up your executable, and what symbols are in each one.

Comment: `The amount of data in the bss segment has no effect on the size on disk of your executable` - Is that statement guaranteed? What about for a different compiler/linker using a coldfire tool chain targeting a uCLinux? `bss` will *never* under *no circumstances* be included in the executable size?

Comment: Yes.  `bss` is by definition only data initialized to zero.  There is no reason for such data to be written to a file.  Recall that this model of a Unix executable was developed on minicomputer systems of the seventies which were actually far *more* resource constrained than today's embedded systems.  :-)

Comment: @Mike - There are no guarantees that all compilers on all systems ever produced will even use a bss segment. That is only a widely used implementation detail.

Comment: Of course.  But it is unlikely that another toolchain (at least on Unix-like systems) will appropriate the name `bss` to mean an actual segment contained in the executable file.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

`bss` is UN-initialized memory.  So the only thing it needs to store is the starting address of each variable and the size.  That's why the executable size only went up by a handful of bytes.

As an aside, even the initialized memory -  the `data` segment - can be smaller in the executable image than the total size of the initialized variables.
 Rather than create a complete image of the initialized data in the executable, many linkers instead insert instructions for how to initialize it.  So if you had done `char buffer[500] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...};`, the `data` part of the executable would conceptually look something like

`&TxBufx: fill with 500 1's`

Except the address would be the literal start of the segment.  But if you added a global `unsigned char bytecode[500] = {0x12, 0x34, 0x55, ... }`, then your data segment would be at least 500 bytes larger, since it couldn't take any shortcuts.